# How to install WSO2 Carbon cluster management feature in new version of Application Server?

Tags: cluster-computing, wso2

I want to manager cluster of Application Server and I follow the guide "http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/install-wso2-carbon-cluster-management-feature/".

In this guide, It applied to Application Server 3.1.0 with P2 repo URL is "http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/3.2.2/", It is OK.

But when I try to apply to Application Server 5.1.0 with P2 repo URL is "http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/3.2.2/"，it can no find any Available Features.
Then I tried other P2 repo URL such as "http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/4.2.0/", it can find some Available Features but without cluster management features.

I want to know what the P2 repo URL is proper for Application Server 5.1.0 to install cluster management feature?

Answer (score 0):

The following link will help to identify the correct carbon version on which the particular product is released. http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/

For application server features, search in terms "app server" and "application server" and for the Application server 5.1.0 use the repo, http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/4.1.0/

Comment: It seems that repo http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/4.1.0/ does not include the cluster management features. I do not understand why it does not include cluster management features in the new repo, but in the old repo http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/3.2.2/, it include cluster management features.

Comment: iceguo, did you find the solution? I am also looking for cluster manager feature in WSO2 AS 5.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Application Server 5.1.0 has cluster management feature installed by default. You can verify it by looking in `repository/components/plugins` folder. There you will see org.wso2.carbon.cluster.mgt.core jar file. So you don't need to install it.

Seems like you are following a outdated tutorial. Follow the [clustering guide](http://docs.wso2.org/display/Cluster/Overview) to learn about clustering WSO2 products.

**EDIT:**

The recommended approach is to have worker/manager separated cluster. Refer the following for info.

http://blog.afkham.org/2012/08/separation-of-worker-management-nodes.html
http://charithaka.blogspot.com/2012/09/setting-up-minimum-deployment-of-wso2.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand what you mean. But how can I manager or monitor the status of the cluster in Mgt Console? I can not find the "cluster" menu in Mgt Console.

Comment: The new recommended approach is to have a worker,manager separated cluster. I don't think the cluster management UI is supported anymore. Refer my edits above to learn more on worker, manager separation.

Comment: I know about worker/manager separated cluster. I still want to know in worker/manager separated cluster, is there a interface for the manager to manage the cluster, including monitor the number of the worker nodes and the status of them, restart or stop the selected worker nodes.